# Typehint a multi-dimensional map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a method in a Groovy file that looks like this:

```
static Map getFixtures() {
    return [
            mydb: [
                    mytable:
                            [
                                    [
                                            Id: 1,

                                    ]
                            ]
            ]
    ]
}
```

When I call the method, like this:

```
  Map fixtures = getFixtures()
```

I get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method getFixtures in class has illegal modifiers: 0x409`

How would I typehint a multidimensional array like this?

Comment: Do you have class declaration in your groovy? Because the error is about method modifier inside class.

Answer (score 0):

Too noob to comment on @dagget 's comment but this may be due to the *get* prefix you chose in your method's name. Groovy maybe trying to make a lookup for a getter method inside the invoking class. Refer to http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_getters_and_setters